# Change animation style of ProgressDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm using mahapps.metro for my app.
When uploading a file I open an indeterminate ProgressDialog. It looks really fancy but the animation is too small.
I want to make it bigger or more visible in either way. I tried to change the ColorScheme to Accented but thats not good enough.

Here is how my code looks like:

```
MetroDialogSettings settings = new MetroDialogSettings {
   ColorScheme = MetroDialogColorScheme.Accented
};
var popup = await this.ShowProgressAsync("Configuration", "text", false, settings);
popup.SetIndeterminate();
await Task.Run(ConfigureTask);
await popup.CloseAsync();
```

Accented is not enough. Is there a way to increase animation size or change the animation to another one like a circle?

Comment: This sort of thing is the reason to think twice before adopting a complicated theme or framework. What's it add. What price do you pay. Personally, I would usually go with my own wait "spinner". Maybe it would be simpler to build one suits what you want to do. You can, however, get all the source code and markup to mahapps and maybe change some of that to your requirement. EG https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/src/MahApps.Metro/Controls/Dialogs/ProgressDialog.xaml